# Cannot assign Generic value to protocol associatedType variable in an extension

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, generics, protocols

I have been struggling my mind with this problem

I am trying to create a bindings structure on Swift, to bind viewModels and controllers in an easy way. So I have created a protocol that defines a variable to be stored on the controller.

```
protocol DVA_MOVVER_ViewControllerProtocolDelegate {
    associatedtype delegateType : DVA_MOVVER_ViewModelProtocol
    var dva_viewModelDelegate : delegateType? { get set }
}
```

As you can see, the variable is restricted to fulfill another protocol, which is this one:

```
protocol DVA_MOVVER_ViewControllerProtocol {
   func dva_tellViewModel()
   // Some other methods
}
```

I want the controller classes only to implement the variable, so it can be a stored variable. I cannot accomplish that using an extension.

So, I have an extension for the second protocol to implement the bindings and to create a common method to bind the variable to the controller

```
extension  DVA_MOVVER_ViewControllerProtocol where Self:DVA_MOVVER_ViewControllerProtocolDelegate  {
    mutating func dva_bindViewModel<T:DVA_MOVVER_ViewModelProtocol>(parameter:T) {

        typealias delegateType = T
        self.dva_viewModelDelegate = parameter
    }
    ...
   // The rest of the DVA_MOVVER_ViewControllerProtocol methods
}
```

And here is where I got stuck. The compiler says “***Cannot assign value of type 'T' to type '_?’***”. I assume this might be because it cannot resolve the parameter type at compile time, but I have no idea how to solve this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by [@rbarbera](https://twitter.com/rbarbera/status/741634364858064896), Type Erasure is the way to go in this cases:

https://realm.io/news/type-erased-wrappers-in-swift/